# Understanding properties of measurable functions.

Tags: measure-theory

A function f on X is said to be $\gamma$ measurable if for every real number $\alpha$ the set $\{x \in \gamma |f(x) > \alpha)$ belongs to $\gamma$ where $\gamma$ is a $\sigma$ algebra of subsets of X.

Then I have that the following statements are equivalent for a function f on X to $\mathbb{R}$.

(a) For every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $A_\alpha= \{x \in \gamma  | f(x) > \alpha \} \in X$

(b) For every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $B_\alpha= \{x \in \gamma  | f(x) \leq  \alpha \} \in X$

(c)For every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $C_\alpha= \{x \in \gamma  | f(x) \geq \alpha \} \in X$

(d) For every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $D_\alpha= \{x \in \gamma  | f(x) < \alpha \} \in X$

I understand that $A_\alpha$ and $B_\alpha$ are compliments of each other hence are equivalent and that $C_\alpha$ and $D_\alpha$ are compliments of each other and hence equivalent.

Now looking to check whether (c) implies (a),

If (a) holds then $A_{\alpha -\frac{1}{n}}$ belongs to X since $c_\alpha = \cap ^\infty _ {n=1} A_{\alpha-\frac{1}{n}}$, How is this clear?

Then the proof says (a) implies (c) since $A_{\alpha} = \cup^\infty _{n=1} C_{\alpha+\frac{1}{n}}$. I do not understand this step, how is this clear?

Answer (score 0):

Use these two fundamental properties :

- a countable union of measurable sets is measurable.
- a countable intersection of measurable sets is measurable.

Comment: But looking at $c_\alpha =\cap^\infty_{n=1} A_{\alpha-\frac{1}{n}}$, WHy is their an intersection but not union?

Comment: @Aljabra : You have that $$\bigcap \{ x | f(x) > \alpha-\frac{1}{n} \} = \{ x | \forall n , f(x) > \alpha - \frac{1}{n} \} = \{ x |  f(x) \geq \alpha  \} $$

Comment: Why did you start of with intersection?

Comment: @Aljabra : because it works?

Comment: I am really not grasping this concept of measurable functions, What would happen if it was a union?

Comment: As I said before (it's in the axioms of a sigma algebra), the countable union of measurable set is measurable

Comment: ok, but then why is there a union in $A_\alpha= \cup ^\infty _{n=1}C_{\alpha  +\frac{1}{n}}$?